# Sed/regex works on a substring in some cases, but not other cases

Tags: regex, sed

I have two strings. The short one...

```
eNews: arch 2002\0 N N
```

...and the long one that contains the short one...

```
449 5344    NULL    2002-03-07 21:17:55 2002-03-07 21:17:55 2002-03-07 21:17:56 2002-03-07 21:17:55 18  N   sent    aqabmdViRA  regular 3NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL            fakeemail@fake.com  Boston Images eNews: March 2002\0   N   N   N       NULL    N   NULL    2014-04-10 20:14:04
```

I am trying to use sed to replace \0, but only when it is not \0 (because that can be part of a date). Each line is in its own file, and I am using the following regex...

```
cat (file) | sed 's/\([^\\]\)\\0 /\1 /g'
```

On the first string, I get the following result...

```
eNews: arch 2002 N N
```

This is good. When I run the same regex on the long one, however, I get the following.

```
449 5344    NULL    2002-03-07 21:17:55 2002-03-07 21:17:55 2002-03-07 21:17:56 2002-03-07 21:17:55 18  N   sent    aqabmdViRA  regular 3NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL            fakeemail@fake.com  Boston Images eNews: March 2002\0   N   N   N       NULL    N   NULL    2014-04-10 20:14:04
```

This still contains the "\0", and I can't figure out why. Anybody have any tips?

edit: The code works when I just echo the line into the cat, but it doesn't work from my csv file.

```
tail test4.csv 
'449    5344    NULL    2002-03-07 21:17:55 2002-03-07 21:17:55 2002-03-07 21:17:56 2002-03-07 21:17:55 18  N   sent    aqabmdViRA  regular 3   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL            fakeemail@fake.com  Boston Images eNews: March 2002\0   N   N   N       NULL    N   NULL    2014-04-10 20:14:04'
cat test4.csv |sed 's/\([^\\]\)\\0 /\1 /g'
'449    5344    NULL    2002-03-07 21:17:55 2002-03-07 21:17:55 2002-03-07 21:17:56 2002-03-07 21:17:55 18  N   sent    aqabmdViRA  regular 3   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL            fakeemail@fake.com  Boston Images eNews: March 2002\0   N   N   N       NULL    N   NULL    2014-04-10 20:14:04'
```

edit 2: As requested,type sed and type cat

```
type sed
sed is /bin/sed
type cat
cat is /bin/cat

cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS"
```

Comment: Are you sure?  It works for me ...

Comment: I just tested it by copying the lines and it did work. When I cat them directly from files (test3.csv and test4.csv), it doesn't work though. I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: `cat`ing from files also seems to work for me. :(

Comment: Damn. Well, thanks. I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Can you include in your post what the results of `type cat` and `type sed` are?  Also what operating system are you using?  Linux, OS X, ...?

Comment: Done. I even went back to the original source file, grepped this line, and piped it into sed. It didn't work.

Comment: `dos2unix test4.csv` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why to use the cat ?

```
sed -e 's/\([^\\]\)\\0[[:space:]]/\1/g' YourFile
```

work directly (like for @dg99) without the problem of echo

Comment: Thanks. I was working with a script and was trying not to change too much. This seems to do the trick, although I still don't know why.